# How can I stop my XCode frameworks from breaking in SVN?

Tags: xcode, svn, frameworks

Here's what happens:

1. I download GoogleAdsFramework and put it in my XCode project folder
2. Now I commit that into SVN
3. If it gets deleted, and I have to pull it down again, the aliases in the framework are broken, so that my XCode includes no longer work.  There is now nothing I can do but remove the framework and replace it with a fresh copy from elsewhere on my mac, so that the aliases are retained.

Does anyone know if there's a way to refresh the aliases in a framework, or otherwise get them to survive an SVN update?